# How Does Berkley DB Cursor Iterate Records

Tags: database, cursor, berkeley-db

I'm using BDB cursor and calling getSaerchKeyRange. From the [docs](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ebdb/berkeley-db/trunk/view/head:/java/src/com/sleepycat/db/Cursor.java#L641)

`getSaerchKeyRange: returns the smallest key greater than or equal to the specified key`

Lets say our DB is the following

```
Key     Value
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
```

After running cursor.`getSearchKeyRange(6)` does the cursor

1. point to 5
2. one record past 5 (which is null? because there are no more
   records)
3. stay where it was (if this was the first search then
   its null?)

So far I've tried reading multiple sources of documentation but the answer isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns "not found".  The way it returns "not found" depends on which programming language you're using.  If you're using Java, it returns `OperationStatus.NOTFOUND`.

In your example, there are no keys in the database that are **greater than or equal to** your search key of 6.  This line in the documentation describes the behavior:

> The returned key/data pair is for the smallest key greater than or equal to the specified key (as determined by the key comparison function), permitting partial key matches and range searches. [source: Oracle Sleepycat Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/je/Cursor.html#getSearchKeyRange-com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseEntry-com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseEntry-com.sleepycat.je.LockMode-)

To round this out, expand on your example by adding some more larger keys:

```
Key     Value
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
37      f
52      g
```

Now, if you do a `getSearchKeyRange(6)`, it returns key `37`.  That's the first key that's greater than or equal to 6.

Comment: If returns not found where is the cursors position

Comment: @anon12345 You're going to have to try it out.  Take your example database, search for "6", get the "not found back", and then call `getPrev()` on it.  The documentation is certainly not clear on this point, even in the underlying C API docs.  When I use this API, I treat the "not found" error as an invalidation of the cursor.  But, as you point out, it's possible the cursor is still valid, pointing past the last record in the database.

Comment: Great thanks. I tested it out and it does move one past the last record. Hopefully this can help others with the same question because the documentation is unclear as you mentioned.